# Ubuntu ISO just for VM?

Tags: iso

Is there an Ubuntu ISO used for virtual machines imaged in vmware or is there one ISO for both physical and virtual?

Answer (score 2):

It's the same ISO.

One of the purposes of a virtual machine is that an OS behaves the same as it does as on a physical machine. (But maybe that's an oversimplification.) Anyway, the booting and installation process is the same on a virtual machine as on a physical.

But, the virtualized OS may require some addons to run better in a VM. For example, the VirtualBox Guest Additions for Ubuntu make it resize Ubuntu's display to fit the size of the VirtualBox window.

Comment: Just to add, there _are_ pre-made virtual machine images of OSes available for download and use on certain VM host software, but these VMDs shouldn't be any different from the result of installing an ISO in a VM; they've just been created beforehand.